# Show binomial coefficient for $x^n$ in the expansion $(1+x)^r(1+x)^s$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

> Show that the binomial coefficient for $x^n$ in the expansion $(1+x)^r(1+x)^s$
>   is $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{r}{k}\binom{s}{n-k}$.

I dont know how to reach that.

What i see is that:

$(1+x)^r(1+x)^s=(1+x)^{r+s} \Rightarrow $ the coefficient is $\binom{r+s}{n}$

And i know $\binom{r+s}{n}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{r}{k}\binom{s}{n-k}$ because it is the Vandermonde's convolution formula.

Comment: Hint: what is the coefficient of $x^n$ in $(a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+...)(b_0+b_1x+b_2x^2+...)$?

Comment: But you can expand each binomial separately and combine $x^j$ and $x^k$ terms.  Now collect like terms where j+k=n.  You proved Vandermonde!

Comment: @ex0du5 I can say $x^kx^{n-k}=x^n$ so the coefficient is $\binom{r}{k}\binom{s}{n-k}$. Still i dont get from where that summatory come from... Im missing something.

Answer (score 3):

We have
$$(1+x)^r(1+x)^s=(1+x)^{r+s}=\sum_{k=0}^{r+s}{r+s\choose k}x^k$$
so the coefficient of $x^n$ is ${r+s\choose n}$.

Moreover
$$(1+x)^r(1+x)^s=\sum_{k=0}^{r}{r\choose k}x^k\sum_{p=0}^{s}{s\choose p}x^p$$
so the coefficient of $x^n$ is
$$\sum_{k+p=n}{r\choose k}{s\choose p}$$
hence we conclude
$$\sum_{k+p=n}{r\choose k}{s\choose p}={r+s\choose n}$$

Comment: So, $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{r}{k}\binom{s}{n-k}$ is the same as $\sum_{k+p=n}{r+s\choose k}{r+s\choose p}$. Im a bit confused with the lower and upper bounds of the sum.